# QCircuit: How to not overlap inputgrupv label with brackets

Tags: qcircuit

I have a problem trying to label a circuit created with QCircuit but the labels keep overlap the brackets. The idea is that I want to add some space between the label and bracket but I couldn't find how. Any help will be appreciated! I also added the code that I use drawing the circuit.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
    \framebox[8cm]{
    
        \Qcircuit @C=1.5em @R=.8em {
        \lstick{}&\lstick{i_{0}}& \multigate{8}{U_{fit}} & \qw    & \rstick{i_{0}} & \\
        & \cdots        & \nghost{U_{fit}}       & \cdots  \\
        \lstick{}&\lstick{i_{N}}& \ghost{U_{fit}}        & \qw    & \rstick{i_{N}} &\\
        \inputgroupv{1}{3}{1.5em}{.8em}{individual}\\
        \lstick{}&\lstick{f_{0}}& \ghost{U_{fit}}        & \qw    & \rstick{f_{0}} &\\ 
        &\cdots        & \nghost{U_{fit}}       & \cdots  \\
        \lstick{}&\lstick{f_{M}}& \ghost{U_{fit}}        & \qw    & \rstick{f_{M}} & \\
        \inputgroupv{5}{7}{1.5em}{.9em}{fitness}\\
        \lstick{}&\lstick{v}    & \ghost{U_{fit}}        & \qw    & \rstick{v} &\\
        }
    }
  \caption{Some caption}
  \label{fig:assessment_subcircuit}
\end{figure}
```